# On noexcept arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The use of `noexcept` was pretty clear to me, as the modern optimized way of marking functions with the **no throw exception guarantee**

```
struct A {
    A() noexcept; 
};
```

In **item 14** of **effective modern c++** I ecountered the following syntax, referred to as **conditionally `noexcept`**

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)));
```

The way I get it, is that `noexcept` can introduce a **truth value context**, but then again how can another **noexcept** be an argument ?

Could someone elaborate on the syntax and semantics of this use of `noexcept` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]) noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)));
                                  (1)      (2)
```

- (1) is a [noexcept specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)
- (2) is a [noexcept operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept)

Comment: So the operator returns bool and that can be used by the specifier. Thnx J

Answer (score 5):

The keyword `noexcept` can be used in two contexts :

1. The [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) which takes an expression as an argument and returns a `bool` indicating whether or not the expression is non-throwing.
2. The [`noexcept` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) which is used to specify whether a function throws or not. This form optionally takes one `bool` constant expression which determines whether the function is `noexcept` or not.

In the code you have pasted,

```
noexcept    ( noexcept(swap(*a, *b)))
^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^
specifier     operator
```